# VB.NET - "Cannot access a closed file" when trying to read contents of a file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Here is my code for the form...

I am attempting to read the contents of files to be able to store in a DB as blob

```
    Try
        Dim fs = New FileStream(TextBox1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim rawData = New Byte(fs.Length) {}
        fs.Read(rawData, 0, fs.Length)
        fs.Close()

        ' Get File size
        Dim filesize As Long = fs.Length

        ' Get Extension
        Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(TextBox1.Text)

        'SQL query
        Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO files VALUES (file_id, @fname, @content, @size, @ext, @comments, @vers, @auth);"

        'commit SQL query with connection statement
        Dim com As New MySqlCommand(cmdText, con)

        'place fields into parameters for the query
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", filename.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", rawData)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", filesize)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ext", extension)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", comments.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vers", version.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@auth", home.userid.Text)

        'this will commit the record to the DB
        con.Close()
        con.Open()
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Comment: can you put the whole exception. I am guessing its the fs.Length access after the close responsble for the exception

Comment: this is correct! stupid error! thank you

Comment: cool... added it as an answer too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the link below, Length property can throw IOException if the file is closed or closing 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.length.aspx

You are accessing the length after closing the file. just flip them as shown below

```
  ' Get File size
   Dim filesize As Long = fs.Length
   fs.Close()
```